# Before the days of the mobile phone (a marker for past/past perfect simple)

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

If you were narrating a personal story with past and past perfect events and then you want to end up your story with "before the days of mobile phones", you say:

> And this ***was*** before the days of mobile phones

not

> And this ***had been*** before the days of mobile phones

and as for the *reasoning* is it because the time of **the days of the mobile phones** is The Present (now), or because there is no past simple event to work as a clear *Reference Time (RT)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't "the days of mobile phones" that you're talking about. It's the referent of "**this**", i.e., your whole story. "The days of mobile phones" is just your reference time (period).  Since your story took place (started and finished) before the days of mobile phones, **was** is the correct choice.

Comment: Okay it is as I thought. Perhaps I was not clear, but I meant exactly as you said. The most important thing to me is that the reference time is now vs before, and now is the period since first mobile invented. Now is like nowadays. The other important tip is how you said that the whole story happened I mean started and finished like a single event; this is cool! Oh, and thank you very much.

Comment: No, the reference time is "the days of mobile phones" and while that is really a time period we are still in, the important point is the beginning of that period.  In other words, let's pick a different reference time period that has actually ended. For example, we'd still say, "that **was** before the days of the Clinton administration."

Comment: Oh, but what comes before **a past** *reference time* is a past perfect whether it is a single event or a longer action that finished by that past reference time. What I've just said and what you said in the answer above about the story being started and finished (even Clinton's which is clearer) have the same weight in terms of argument even though I know the right choice is **was**. It's a matter of reasoning. I could not get a clear cut.

Comment: In other words, what holds someone back from saying: "And this **had been** before the days of mobile phones" is ALSO possible, i.e both are Okay? Would your argument be that the story and what comes after the story are like two narrative events. I mean when you (the narrator) say this happened before some thing, you are actually narrating events, like other narrative events inside the story?!

Comment: I think my last reasoning about the narrator is right, because the narrator is telling the time of events, or in other words he is giving us the order of events which is similar or exactly as giving an account of some ordered events. And this is what the simple past for. Am I right?

Comment: Simple put, this was before that. A was before B.

Comment: *had been* implies that it is (or could be) different now, at the time of telling.

Comment: Damkerng T. quoted the following from @Snailboat I believe. "Often, your choice of words implies a certain aspect.

I **have been** eating spaghetti **since** 3AM. [ = I was eating then and I still am now.]
I **had been** eating spaghetti **until** I realized all food was evil. [ = I stopped eating spaghetti when I made that realization.]
*When I hear **had been**, my ear expects to hear some reason why the state is no longer in effect.*" - So can I infer from your last comment that **was** is **neutral**? Sorry for asking a lot, Jim!

Comment: @learner I believe that even in narration, *A was before B* is the good (maybe even the only) choice; unless there is a *was* inside B, then it should become *A had been before [B-subj was B-predicate]*.